# How to receive SMS massages from a specific number?

Tags: java, android, sms-gateway

> i want to receive messages form a specific number but when i run the app i get messages from everyone in my inbox i got the source code from this [site(android authority)](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-create-an-sms-app-721438/)

```
 package com.nqr.smsapp;

 import android.Manifest; import android.content.ContentResolver;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager; import
 android.database.Cursor; import android.net.Uri; import
 android.support.annotation.NonNull; import
 android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; import
 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.SmsManager; import android.view.View; import
 android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.EditText; import
 android.widget.ListView; import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<>();
     ListView messages;
     ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
     EditText input;
     SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
     private static MainActivity inst;

     private static final int READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1;

     public static MainActivity instance() {
         return inst;
     }

     @Override
     public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         inst = this;
     }


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         messages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
         input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
         arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
         messages.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             getPermissionToReadSMS();
         } else {
             refreshSmsInbox();
         }


     }

     public void updateInbox(final String smsMessage) {
         arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
         arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

    public void onSendClick(View view) {

     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         getPermissionToReadSMS();
     } else {
         smsManager.sendTextMessage("07911127456", null, input.getText().toString(), null, null);
         Toast.makeText(this, "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } }

         public void getPermissionToReadSMS() {
             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                     != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                         Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
                     Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                         READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
             }
         }


     @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                            @NonNull String permissions[],
                                            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
         // Make sure it's our original READ_CONTACTS request
         if (requestCode == READ_SMS_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
             if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                     grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Read SMS permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 refreshSmsInbox();
             } else {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "Read SMS permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

             } else {
                 super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
             }



         }

             public void refreshSmsInbox() {
             ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
             Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null,
 null, null);
             int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
             int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
             if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
             arrayAdapter.clear();
             do {
                 String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                         "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
                 arrayAdapter.add(str);
             } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext()); //messages.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getCount() - 1);
     }



 }
>
```

> i want the messages to be delivered from a specific number to my inbox: for instance messages only from 07911 127456 in my inbox

i only need a specific conversation from the SMS inbox,   please help me!!!

> ***broadcast recevier***

```
package com.nqr.smsapp;


        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

            if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);

                String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
            }

            MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
            inst.updateInbox(smsMessageStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. Edit your original question to include all the details.